# Mod_evasive No logs, No IP blocking, No errors - What's going on?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, mod-security

I'm experiencing an anomaly on my Ubuntu 16.04 Machine. I installed LAMP, ufw, fail2ban e now as a DOS protection I installed mod_evasive.

Mod_evasive doesn't seem to block anything, doesn't log anything and the only log I see in var/log/apache2/error.logs when I reload a page fast enough to trigger it is:

```
[evasive20:error] [pid 17849] [client *..***.179:9189] client denied by server configuration:..
```

Beside that NOTHING.

I went through all the steps, created a log directory, give permissions, reinstalled, tried all sort of things but the problem doesn't seem to be fixed AT ALL!

This is my current configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
DOSHashTableSize    3097
DOSPageCount        1
DOSSiteCount        5
DOSPageInterval     1
DOSSiteInterval     1
DOSBlockingPeriod   15

#DOSEmailNotify      you@yourdomain.com
#DOSSystemCommand    "su - someuser -c '/sbin/... %s ...'"
DOSLogDir           "/var/log/apache2/evasive.log"
</IfModule>
```

Any idea?
EDIT:
I'm now able to see the logs-> IT basically logs files named DOS-203.33.**.* for each presumed attack. 
But still it doesn't block anything! From my understanding it has to block the ip address at the Apache level but it doesnt..

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are missing the firewall-part.
if you are using iptables you should set the following **DOSSystemCommand**:

```
"sudo /root/scripts/ban_ip.sh %s":
```

be sure to add your apache user to sudoers and allow access to the script and 'iptables' and 'at' command.

**Script content**:

```
#!/bin/sh

IP=$1
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

$IPTABLES -A banned -s $IP -p TCP --dport 80 -j DROP

echo "$IPTABLES -D banned -s $IP -p TCP --dport 80 -j DROP" | at now + 2 hours
```

**sudoers**:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables *, /usr/bin/at *, /root/scripts/ban_ip.sh
```

cheers!

Comment: Adding apache user to sudoers is a security risk!

Comment: Please do not add apache user to sudoers.